# Primitive roots of a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, primitive-roots

I understand the definition of a primitive root of integers; however, I am quite confused trying to find the primitive roots of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3-x+\overline{1})}$. I know that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3-x+\overline{1})}$ has elements of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, with $a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so it has $27$ elements, and $\mathbb{F}_{27} \simeq \frac{\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3-x+\overline{1})}$.

Also, it is not clear to me if I must find an element of order 26 or an element of order $\varphi(27) = 18$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler Totient Function.

Could someone give me a tip?

Comment: You have to find an element of order $26$ since the multiplicative group of $\Bbb F_{27}$ has order $26$

Comment: Perfectly, but, you have any idea about how to find it without brutal force?

Comment: Pointing at [a quick way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2772811/11619) though the polynomial there has a crucial difference. Use Freshman's dream aka the Frobenius automorphism. If $\alpha$ is a zero of $x^3-x+1$ then $\alpha^3=\alpha-1$, hence $\alpha^9=\alpha-2=\alpha+1$. Hence
$$\alpha^{13}=\alpha^{1+3+9}=\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha+1)=\alpha^3-\alpha=-1.$$
It follows that $\alpha$ has order $26$ and is thus primitive.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I concluded that in a simmilar way, however, how do I find the others, if there are?

Comment: From the theory of cyclic groups you should remember that if $g$ has order $n$, the the order of $g^k$ is $n/\gcd(n,k)$. So $\alpha^k$ is another primitive element whenever $\gcd(k,26)=1$.

Comment: Not voting to close as a duplicate. The duplication is not exact so I will not use my dupehammer while pointing at my own answer.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I studied cyclic groups some time ago. Thanks for you help, and, so, the primitive roots of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ are $p, p^3, p^5,p^7,p^9, p^{11}, p^{15}, p^{17}, p^{19}, p^{21}, p^{23}, p^{25}$, right?

Comment: Correct. The odd exponents $k<26$ will do. With the single exception $k=13$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Leoli1](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/649658/leoli1) commented, you have to find an element of order $26$,

since the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_{27}$ has order $26$.

You may consider this brute force, but using $x^3\equiv x-1$ we have

$x^4\equiv x^2-x, $ $x^5\equiv -x^2+x-1$, $x^6\equiv x^2+x+1$, $x^7\equiv x^2+2x+2$, $x^8\equiv2x^2-1$,

$x^9\equiv x+1, x^{10}\equiv x^2+x$, $x^{11}\equiv x^2+x-1$, $x^{12}\equiv x^2-1$, and $x^{13}\equiv-1$.

It follows that $x$ is a primitive root.

(I could have taken a short cut:  $x^{12}\equiv (x^4)^3\equiv (x^2-x)^3\equiv(x^2)^3-x^3= x^6-x^3$

$=x^3(x^3-1)\equiv (x-1)(x-2)\equiv (x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$.)

Comment: I concluded that in a simmilar way, however, how do I find the others, if there are?

Comment: use that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic

Comment: I studied cyclic groups some time ago. Thanks for you help, and, so, the primitive roots of $\mathbb{F}_{27}$ are $p,p^3,p^5,p^7,p^9,p^{11,}p^{15},p^{17},p^{19},p^{21},p^{23},p^{25}$, right? @J. W. Tanner

Comment: You're welcome @Anyway142; that's right, where $p$ is a primitive root