# Given irreducible polynomial find $n$-th primitive root of unity

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, coding-theory, roots-of-unity

Consider a cyclic code of length $13$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$. Its cyclotomic cosets are
$$C_0=\{0\},\,C_1=\{1,3,9\},\,C_2=\{2,6,5\},\,C_4=\{4,12,10\},\,C_5=\{7,8,11\}$$
and so there can only be $1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12$ (and $13$) dimensional cyclic codes of length $13$.

Now, I want to find a primitive $13$th-root of unity. I showed that $x^3+2x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$. This fact helps me find such primitive root of unity but I can't seem to figure this out.

Moreover, knowing the above, how can I say that $g(x)=x^7+2x^6+x^5+2x^4+x^2+2$ is a generator for a $[13,6,d]$ cyclic code with $d\geq 5$?

I appreciate any help on these two questions. Thanks in advance!

Comment: See [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2772811/11619).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! So, I understand that $t^{13}=2$, where $t$ is a root of $x^3+2x+1$. But I don't know how to find such primitive $13$-root of unity. Also, knowing this, how can I argue that $g(x)$ generates such cyclic code?

Comment: Then $(-t)^{13}=-2=1$, and $\alpha=-t$ is a primitive thirteenth root of unity. Because
$t^3+2t=t^3-t=-1$ it follows that $(-t)^3-(-t)=-(t^3-t)=1$. So $m(x)=x^3-x-1$ can be chosen to correspond to the cyclotomic coset $C_1$. Do you know how to find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^2=t^2$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't know how to find it.

Comment: There are general methods for find the minimal polynomials of elements in an extension field. For squares there is the following trick. We know that $\alpha$ is a a zero of $m(x)=x^3-x-1$. Therefore $\alpha$ is also a zero of
$$m(x)m(-x)=-(x^3-x-1)(x^3-x+1)=1-(x^3-x)^2=1-x^2+2x^4-x^6.$$
Observe that in this product only even powers of $x$ appear (do you see why that will happen to every $m(x)$?). Therefore $\alpha^2$ is a zero of $x^3+x^2+x-1$.

Comment: Hmm. I got a different degree seven polynomial. Oops,  I was working under the assumption that you want a BCH-code. Rethink....

Comment: Never mind. I got the reciprocal polynomial of yours. That produces and equivalent code with the symbol order reversed.